# Node js mongoDb client bulk insert data using promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

Hi I am beginner in node js mongodb. I want to insert data in mongodb. First I check user exist in users collection then data insert and after complete process then callback.  Please give suggestion

```
   exports.contactSync = function contactSync(data, userId, callback) {

    var Promise = require('promise');
    MongoClient.connect(Mongo_url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db.collection('contacts').deleteMany({user_id: userId});
       var bulk = db.collection('contacts').initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
            counter = 0;

    data.forEach(function (doc) {
        let promises = [];
        db.collection('users').findOne({email: doc.trim()}, {user_id: 1}).then(function (userData) { 
            promises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
                bulk.insert({user_id: userId, contact_id: userData.user_id});
            }));
        });

        counter++;

        if (data.length == counter) { 
             return Promise.all(promises);
            bulk.execute(function (err, r) {
                // do something with the result
                     console.log("succes");
            });
        }
    }); 

    if (counter > 0) {
        bulk.execute(function (err, result) {
            console.log("succes"); 
            callback({'error': 0, 'message': 'Successfull synchronization', 'data': null, 'status': 200});
            // do something with the result here
        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The buld.execute is unreachable

```
if (data.length == counter) { 
             return Promise.all(promises);
            bulk.execute(function (err, r) {
                // do something with the result
                     console.log("succes");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inserMany() method to insert bulk data into MongoDB.

example with the promise:

```
Collection1.insertMany(myData)
    .then(function(docs) {
         // do something with docs
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // error handling here
    });
```

Comment: I know insert many. but before insert how can check user exist or not

Answer (score 0):

I given the sample you just idea follow the ways for insert bulk data with promise

```
//var Q = require('q'); 
//insertData = [{name: "abcd"},{name: "efgh"},{name: "xyz"}]
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var spec = {};
    var deleteData= req.deleteData;
    Q(spec).then(function(spec) {
     //add your delete records logic
     var deferred = Q.defer();
    var collection = collection_name;
    //here assign your db with collection name
    collection.deleteMany(deleteData, function(err, user) {
        if (!err && user) {
            spec.delete= user;
            deferred.resolve(spec);
        } else {
            spec.message = "Please retry";
            deferred.reject(spec);
        }
    });
        return deferred.promise;
    }).then(function(spec) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var collection = collection_name;
    //here assign your db with collection name
    collection.insertMany(insertData, function(err, user) {
        if (!err && user) {
            spec.user = user;
            deferred.resolve(spec);
        } else {
            spec.message = "Please retry";
            deferred.reject(spec);
        }
    });
        return deferred.promise;
    }).then(function(spec) {
        res.json(spec);
        //send your response
    }).fail(function(spec) {
        res.json(spec);
        //send your error response
    });
}
```